# Trouble updating API object once instantiated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I'm instantiating a new Vimeo object when clicked. This allows me to use the event target to grab the videoUrl depending on which element is clicked. Then the vimeo api automagically creates an iframe with the video embed. The problem is that once the Vimeo player is created, I can't destroy it and recreate it with another videoUrl. It stays stuck on the first element I clicked. If I refresh and click another element, it works with the new videoUrl, so it means that it works on any element I choose but only the first click. I'm guessing this is a JS issue that I'm not familiar with. I'm used to C++ where we can use pointers to address this kind of thing. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
function openModal(e) {
    var modal = document.getElementById('Modal');
    var videoUrl = e.target.dataset.videoLink;
    //JS Player Code
    alert(e.target.dataset.videoLink);
    var options = {
        url: videoUrl,
        width: 640,
        loop: false
    };
    var player = new Vimeo.Player('Modal', options);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    //Doesn't seem to do anything
    delete player;
}
```

Comment: The `delete` operator is used to delete object properties; you can't use it to delete local variables. But in any case, there is a difference between removing a variable or property and removing the object referenced by a variable or property.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C++, JavaScript has a garbage collector in which you don't have to manage your memory. The `delete` operator in JS is completely different than the one you have in C++. Instead of pointers, JS uses "references" which you can't destroy manually.

Now, I don't quite understand what you expect to happen when you do `delete player`. But I assume you want to remove the `iframe` (which doesn't really make any sense.)

But anyway, you have two choices. You either

1. Hide it with CSS via `display: none`
2. Replace the element with a new one.

By the way, the `delete` operator in JS is equivalent to the `std::map::erase` method in C++.

Comment: So, the vimeo api allows you to select an empty element, in this case 'Modal', and it will automagically append an iframe inside. I did accomplish removing the iframe in another function when the user closes the modal. That's not the issue. But what's weird is that on clicking again, the openModal function doesn't create a new object. It does nothing. If I deactive the iframe deleting function, it just stays stuck on the video url I first selected. So something is telling me that object stays floating around and JS does not like me trying to create objects inside a function. I'm very confused.

Comment: *"JS does not like me trying to create objects inside a function"* - JS doesn't have a problem with that, that's a standard thing to do. Have you tried removing the `'Modal'` DOM element and recreating it before calling `new Vimeo.Player(...)`?

Comment: "*I did accomplish removing the iframe in another function*" - Are you sure about that?

Comment: @nnnnnn That's it! I coudn't just delete the iframe. I had to delete the entire container wrapping it. I created an empty div inside the Modal to wrap the iframe. Now I just delete the whole Div and when I create the object again, it sets the new iframe as expected. Thanks!! Now, why is it that the DOM behaves like this? Is it the DOM or JS?

Comment: I don't think the blame is with the DOM *or* JS in the sense of there being anything inherently generically wrong with either. I'm not familiar with the `Vimeo` API object, but I would guess maybe it has been coded to store references against the DOM element or something and that that information is retained when you call `Vimeo.Player()` again for the same element. (Perhaps it has some other methods that allow resetting or re-use of the same DOM element.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Well thanks. I think you should post an answer to give you credit.